# Linux - when is /proc/PID created?

Tags: linux, bash, proc

I'm writing a Bash script to monitor a process and detect when it has crashed. To do this, I am monitoring the /proc directory;

```
start_my_process;
my_process_id=$!;
until [[ ! -d "/proc/$my_process_pid" ]]; do
   # alert the process is dead and restart it...
done
```

Can I be guaranteed that the process's entry in /proc/ will be created BEFORE Bash finishes executing the command to start the process? Or is it possible that by time my check above is executed, the entry for start_my_process might not yet be created?

**EDIT:**
In the end I actually went against a custom solution and chose monit which is an excellent watchdog tool.

Comment: Is your question actually "how do I detect whether a backgrounded process is still alive?"

Comment: Possibly. The above is just how I have chosen to do it. I want to detect if the process is dead AS SOON AS it is dead.

Comment: @Boon there a lot of common patterns to do that, for instance monit, have you tried it?

Comment: @Cyrus - why on Earth would I want to do that?

Comment: If you start your process with a trailing `&`, try this: `while true; do start_my_process &; wait; done`

Comment: @Boon Starting the process (and waiting for it) in a loop is the best way to do this, especially if you use one of the daemonizing tools whose job it is to do this robustly. Your suggest way of polling `/proc` is slow and racy, and I'd strongly recommend deleting this question and finding/asking a new one about how to restart a process when it dies. (also see [XYProblem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`/proc/<pid>` is never created. It is not a real directory.

`/proc` is a virtual filesystem. When you open one of its "files" and read from its output stream, the data are being provided by the kernel. Since the kernel is also responsible for managing process `<pid>`, the kernel will tell you that `/proc/<pid>` directory exists as soon as and for as long as the kernel is keeping track of it.

Since bash won't be able to set `$!` until the process exists, you are definitely safe checking for the process's virtual directory under `/proc` after that time.